# Won't able to zoom after including chartjszoom in chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

Failed to zoom after include the correct version of chartjs and chartjs-plugin-zoom.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.7/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
```

This is my canvas tag

```
<div class='chart-wrapper'>
  <div class="training-chart-area" style="width: 768px; height: 384px;">
    <canvas id="trainingChart1"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

My plugin option in my chart js function

```
options: {
      plugins: {
        zoom: {
          zoom: {
              enabled: true,  
              mode: 'y'
          },
          pan: {
              enabled: true
          }
        }
}
```

I know I have the correct version because I tested it with another HTML file. I thought the problem may be chartjs-plugin-zoom won't work with multiple datasets within one chart, but test HTML worked perfectly fine. I have no idea where went wrong.

Comment: It seems to work fine with what you shared (https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/87k0jrxc/1/), can you either share a reproducable sample of why it doesnt work or any console errors you might be getting?

Comment: I found out what the problem is, I include chartjs twice, once with cdn the other locally. Once I deleted the local inclusion, everything worked perfectly. Thanks for the reply.